# AWS SES send mail with credentials

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to send email by AWS SES sesMail. But I need to set security credentials while sending email. I read documentation of SES for grails and it states that we need to set it as following,

```
mailId = sesMail {
 credentials "new_access_key", "new_security_key"
 to "email@gmail.com"
 subject "test plain text mail"
 body "this is the e-mail content"
}
```

But it doesn't work. There is no error. the mail id it returns is NULL. And no emails are sent. Anyone has solution how to do this?

Comment: What is the error? "Doesn't work" doesn't mean much!

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy : It has no errors or exception. I've edited that in question. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: There is no "from" parameter there. Do you set it somewhere else or not included here? If not I'd try with that as well

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy : I tried with including 'from' attribute. It didn't worked. I had included 'from' in config.groovy. I found solution though. Posting it in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't send the new credentials in a way above. So there is another method to do it.

```
def credentialsHolder = new AWSCredentialsHolder();
credentialsHolder.accessKey = bean?.accessKey
credentialsHolder.secretKey = bean?.secreteKey
def sender = new SendSesMail();
sender.credentialsHolder = credentialsHolder;
sender.region = bean?.region        
mailId = sender.send {
                from fromEmail
                to toEmail
                subject "new subject"
                body "e-mail body (plain text)"
            }
```

Make sure you provide correct `region` else it gives error of 'Email id not verified'.